# How do I access the first values of lists contained in a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary where each key has a list as value, i.e.

```
my_dict={"k":[], "kr":[]}

for i in range (10):
    my_dict['k'].append(rand.uniform(12,60))
    my_dict['kr'].append(rand.uniform(0.1,.3))
```

How can I access the first value of the lists corresponding to `'k'` and `'kr'`?

Comment: dict['k'][0] or dict['kr'][0]?

Comment: Your question shows no research done, we really don't appreciate these kind of questions. Please take a tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[list Indexing](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list#index)** to access elements of a list

EX:

```
dict={
"k":[],
"kr":[]}


for i in range (10):
    dict['k'].append(rand.uniform(12,60))
    dict['kr'].append(rand.uniform(0.1,.3))

print(dict['k'][0])     List elements starts from 0
print(dict['kr'][0])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need the first element of *each* value, consider using list comprehensions:

```
[l[0] for l in dict.values()]
```